# New line between fields in TCA in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I am searching the way for adding a new line between my fields in TYPO3 backend.

Here is my TCA code:

```php
    'tx_name' => array(
        'label'     => 'Your name',
        'config'    => array(
            'type'        => 'input',
            'size'        => '600',
        )
    ),
```

and then the palette:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['palettes']['mypallete'] = array(
    'showitem' => 'tx_name, tx_surename, tx_....'
);
```

I would like to have name, surname always in the new line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should include there string `--linebreak--`

So in your code it will be like this:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['palettes']['mypallete'] = array(
    'showitem' => 'tx_name,--linebreak--,tx_surename,--linebreak--, tx_....'
);
```

So right now you should have every field on new line.